# mongoose mapreduce()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am keeping track of players' scores in order to record growth. My schema is as follows:

```
Schema = new schema({
    pid: { type: Number }
  , name: { type: String }
  , alliance: {
      aid: { type: Number }
    , name: { type: String }
    }
  , city_cnt: { type: Number }
  , score: { type: Number }
  , rank: { type: Number }
  , createdTimeAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
  , createdDayAt: { type: Number, default: function() { return Math.floor(Date.now() / (24 * 60 * 60)) } }
})
```

Now I want to pull out one record per day (being the last recorded score for that day) per player. So I have this map reduce:

```
growthMap = function(){
  emit('createdTimeAt', this.createdTimeAt.toString())
}

growthReduce = function(prev, doc) { 
  if (doc.createdTimeAt > prev.createdTimeAt) {
    prev.createdTimeAt = doc.createdTimeAt
    prev.score = doc.score

    prev.pid = doc.pid
    prev.name = doc.name
  }
}

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/my_database')
mongoose.model('Players', Schema)

mongoose.connection.db.executeDbCommand({
  mapreduce: 'players'
, map: growthMap.toString()
, reduce: growthReduce.toString()
, out: 'playerGrowth'
}, function(err, ret){ 
  if (err) console.log(err)
  else {
    console.log(ret.documents)
    mongoose.connection.db.collection('playerGrowths', function(err, collection){
      collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, docs){
        console.dir(docs)
      })

    })
  }
})
```

The map reduce seems to work fine. The first output *console.log(ret.documents)* produces this result:

```
[ { result: 'playerGrowth',
    timeMillis: 11268,
    counts: { input: 14635, emit: 14635, reduce: 15, output: 1 },
    ok: 1 } ]
```

However, whenever I try to query the new collection in the second output *console.log(docs)*, I get an empty array with no results. I'm sure I am doing something wrong, but the mongoose documentation is lacking when it comes to mapreduce.

#### EDIT

As per Jed's answer below I changed *mongoose.connection.db.collection('playerGrowths'* to *mongoose.connection.db.collection('playerGrowth'* and I'm at least getting a result from the find({}).toArray(). However, it's still not what I'm expecting or need...

**My new results**

```
[ { result: 'playerGrowth',
    timeMillis: 5743,
    counts: { input: 14635, emit: 14635, reduce: 15, output: 1 },
    ok: 1 } ]
null
[ { _id: 'createdTimeAt', value: null } ]
```

Comment: I think, and correct me if I'm wrong Jed, but the plurality you see in model/collection names is mongoose-caused, and when we get down to this level calling mapReduce, we're talking to mongodb, who doesn't do that with the names.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
mongoose.connection.db.collection('playerGrowths'...
```

To:

```
mongoose.connection.db.collection('playerGrowth'...
```

Comment: Hmmm, at least I'm not getting an empty array anymore. Now it's giving me **[ { _id: 'createdTimeAt', value: null } ]**

Comment: Try changing the name of your model to player and then set mapreduce to: players

Comment: Better for model to be Player with capital P, actually.

Answer (score 0):

The result of the mapreduce is just some diagnostics. Now you need to query the playerGrowth collection for the actual results produced.

Answer (score 0):

The emit() function should return a key-value pair. Since your "key" is "createdTimeAt", its what it aggregates results by. You should probably do:

```
emit(this.createdTimeAt.toString(), <your value>)
```