# Taking sum/average of columns in mongoosejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a MongoDB collection "Marks" with fields student_id,Subject,Mark.
I want to the average value of marks scored by a particular student.
My project is in NodeJs and I am using MongooseJS for object modeling.
How to query the this using MOngooseJS?

**EXAMPLE**

```
     Student_id   Subject  Mark
     111          AAA      9
     111          BBB      5
     111          CCC      7
     222          AAA      10
     222          CCC      6
     222          BBB      8
```

I want average of marks scored by student(id) 111 i.e((9+5+7)/3)=7)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're using MongoDB 2.2 you can use the aggregation framework for this:

```
var Mark = mongoose.model('mark', new Schema({
    Student_id: Number,
    Subject: String,
    Mark: Number
}));

Mark.aggregate([
        { $group: {
            _id: '$Student_id',
            markAvg: { $avg: '$Mark'}
        }}
    ], function (err, results) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
        } else {
            console.log(results);
        }
    }
);
```

Output:

```
[ { _id: 222, markAvg: 8 }, { _id: 111, markAvg: 7 } ]
```

Comment: I tried this,but got error-- 500 TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'setMaxListeners' at Object.Document 
Another thing my MONGODB Version is 2.0.5 .
Also, my models and controllers are separate 'js'-file.I refer to model as-model.model_name.aggregate([
        { $group:..... This is how I wrote code in controller.Can you please tell why this error occurred

Comment: This is the error --500 TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'setMaxListeners'
at Object.Document (D:\MED_NETWRK\medinfo.api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:30:8)
at Object.Model (D:\MED_NETWRK\medinfo.api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:26:12)
at Object.model [as Doctor] (D:\MED_NETWRK\medinfo.api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:910:11)
at controller.getDoctor (D:\MED_NETWRK\medinfo.api\controllers\DoctorController.js:54:20)
at callbacks (D:\MED_NETWRK\medinfo.api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:272:11)... and some more lines.

Comment: @dany That's because you're using MongoDB 2.0.5 but the aggregation framework requires 2.2+.  Can you upgrade to 2.2?

Comment: I need the average mark of only ONE student at a time.i.e I pass student_id -111 and I want answer 7.How to do this?

Comment: For that, add a [`$match`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/match/#_S_match) element to the start of the `aggregate` pipeline of: `{ $match: { Student_id: 111 } }`

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like the poster child example of a Map/Reduce operation in MongoDB.

What you want to do is first run a map step where you emit all grades that belong to student id 111.
Then you run the reduce step where you average these.

The monogdb code should look similar to this:

```
var map = function() {
  emit(this.Student_id, this.Mark);
}
var reduce = function(key, values) {
  var result = { studentid: key, mark_sum: 0, count: 0, avg_mark: 0 };
  values.forEach(function(v) {
    r.mark_sum += v;
    r.count += 1;
  });
  return r;
}

var finalize = function(key, value) {
  if (value.count > 0) {
    value.avg_mark = value.mark_sum / value.count;
  }
  return value;
}
```

And the execution of the mapReduce in Mongo syntax:

```
var command = db.runCommand( { mapreduce:"<your collection>",
                  map: map,
                  reduce: reduce,
                  query: { Student_id: 111 },
                  out: { reduce: "session_stat" },
                  finalize: finalize
                });
```

The result of the map_reduce is written to `session_stat`. Where you can query it.

To see how to use MapReduce in Mongoose please look at this Question: [mongoose mapreduce()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8843264/mongoose-mapreduce)

Comment: Thank you. But I am a beginner so I didn't understood completely how to bring this as Mongoose  query.

Comment: I edited the answer with a reference to a MapReduce question with Mongoose here on SO.